# UIImageView animations not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

I'm trying to use UIImageView to animate a lamp switching on and off. I have two images, one with a glow and the other without. This should be very simple and I'm sure I've done this before with no problem, yet my code just isn't working. Here's what I have:

```
UIImage *glow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Glow.png"];
UIImage *noGlow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No Glow.png"];
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:noGlow, glow, nil];

self.lampImage.animationImages = images;
self.lampImage.animationDuration = 1.0;

[self.lampImage startAnimating];

NSLog(@"%d", self.lampImage.isAnimating); // prints 1 
NSLog(@"%d", self.lampImage.animationRepeatCount); // prints 0
```

At the moment I have this code in my viewDidLoad. If I run the app with the above code, all I see is the NoGlow image. If I swap the order in the images array (glow, noGlow, nil) and run the app again, I just see the Glow image instead.

According to the logs, it is animating and the repeat count is 0, meaning it should keep animating indefinitely. Why am I not seeing any animation?

I'm testing this in the iOS 5.1 and 6.1 simulator with the same results for both.

Comment: Did you check if both images are not nil? I tried the code out and it worked for me. Check if your images are loaded and are not nil. Also check that your imageView called lampImage is connected if created in the xib file.

Comment: Try adding an animation count and an auto reverse to make sure it's not animating before the view is visible.

Comment: I tried it in the viewDidLoad method, Eric, and it worked in my test project.

Comment: try to rename the file No Glow.png with No_Glow.png

Comment: @SimonePistecchia You got it. My image was named "NoGlow.png", but in my code I had referenced it as "No Glow.png".You should post your solution as an answer and I will accept it for you. Thanks!

Comment: But its not the correct answer like Simone posted it as answer! Because its possible to name a file with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your error is the different name of your file or image name.
Try to rename the file No Glow.png with No_Glow.png for don't fall in error

Comment: Just to make it clear for others who are gonna read this. It is no problem to name a file with a space in the filename!

Comment: it's very recommendable to never use space for file name!

Comment: Yes, it's not the exact answer but it is the answer that helped me solve the problem. My image was named "NoGlow.png", but in my code I had referenced it as "No Glow.png". I've often used images in Xcode projects that have a space in the name and not had any problems.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia of course it is, but between "recommendable" and "not allowed" is a big difference :)